# Returning false from underscore each appears to end the loop

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have encountered some baffling behavior with Underscore's `_.each` function. I have the following in a base class for a set of objects I'm creating:

```js
constructor(properties = {}, options = {}) {
  // lets me replace UUID generator function for testing, and for a
  // special-case id used by a singleton subclass
  _.defaults(options, {generateUuid});
  _.chain(properties)
      .keys()
      .reject((k) => k === 'id' || k === '_id')
      .each((k) => this[k] = properties[k])
      .value();
  this._id = options.generateUuid();
}
```

When testing the constructor for my first large subclass, I passed in a large number of properties (numbers, strings, and booleans). My Chai assertion failed at the 43rd property (of 61), which was immediately following the first `false` value. The error claimed that the property did not exist.

The current state of the subclass in question is simply:

```js
constructor(properties = {}) {
  if (typeof properties.subtype !== 'undefined') {
    properties._subtype = properties.subtype;
  }
  // etc. for several more aliased properties
  _.defaults(properties, {
    _subtype: 'token',
    // etc. for default property values
  });
  super({
    _type: 'graphic',
    _subtype: properties._subtype,
    // etc. for all whitelisted properties
  });
}
```

While trying to debug the problem, I confirmed that all of the properties and their correct values were being passed to the superclass constructor, but that all properties following the first `false` did not get added to `this`. It was only when I added trace debugging to the `.each` that things really changed:

```js
_.chain(properties)
    .keys()
    .reject((k) => k === 'id' || k === '_id')
    .each((k) => {
      console.log(k);
      this[k] = properties[k];
    })
    .value();
```

Suddenly, all of the properties were present in the object and my test passed! Since a single-line arrow function (without brackets) is returning the value of its single expression (while a multi-line arrow function is by default returning undefined), and the expression `foo = bar` returns bar, my only conclusion is that returning `false` from `_.each` was ending the loop.

So, I set out to investigate why that would be the case. I grabbed the Underscore source code (v1.8.3, the same version I'm running) to see if there was special handling specifically to accomplish that result (which would conveniently allow client code to `break` from an `_.each` loop):

```js
_.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = optimizeCb(iteratee, context);
  var i, length;
  if (isArrayLike(obj)) {
    for (i = 0, length = obj.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
    }
  } else {
    var keys = _.keys(obj);
    for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
      iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};
```

When `context` is falsy, `optimizeCb(iteratee, context)` immediately returns `iteratee`. There's nothing here that should break out early when `iteratee` returns false.

Does anyone have an explanation for the behavior I'm observing?

Comment: Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Are you sure it is UnderscoreJS and not Lodash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are using [lodash](https://lodash.com/) and not [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

From [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach):

> The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection). *Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning `false`*.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! One of my other Bower dependencies apparently installed Lodash in addition to my explicit dependency on Underscore. `_` in my console gave me `function lodash(value)...`. After calling `_.noConflict()`, it results in `function (n)...`